# Failed to display the text beside progress bar

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar, android-progressbar

How to make the `test%` display beside the `progress bar` ? I use    `android:layout_toLeftOf` and 
            `android:layout_toStartOf` , but it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListProject"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/downloadProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="20dip"
            android:maxHeight="20dip"
            android:minWidth="130dip"
            android:maxWidth="130dip"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ListProject"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ListProject"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/downloadProgressBar"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/downloadProgressBar"
            android:paddingLeft="100dp"
            android:text="Test %"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListTimeIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListTimeOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**After remove    android:paddingLeft="100dp"**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextView test % not show because its paddingLeft = 100dp

or you can remake Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListProject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/downloadProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ListProject2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="20dip"
        android:maxHeight="20dip"
        android:minWidth="130dip"
        android:maxWidth="130dip"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListProject2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test %"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```